# Cors React and Gin-Gonic Gin

Tags: reactjs, go, cors, go-gin

I have run into a problem implementing cross origin resource sharing in the development environment, between a react front end and Go-lang Gin-Gonic framework, below is the console log from the browser
[image: Console log for react application sending a post request]

[image: This is the received request from the Go framework, as can be seen, the preflight request is not validated]

Console log from the react application sending a post request

This is the received request from the Go framework, as can be seen, the preflight request is not validated

I have attempted two hacks, one is validating the preflight request and passing a 200 on the react OPTIONS as seen below

```
func preflight(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-headers")
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, struct{}{})
}
```

This hack was not of help, additionally ,i included a middleware with a wildcard domain in the access control allow origin, as well as with http://localhost:3000 as shown below

```
func CORSMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {

        c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
        c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,HEAD,PATCH, OPTIONS, GET, PUT")

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(204)
            return
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}
```

I also tried the gin cors package as shown here github.com/gin-contrib/cors but the request is still being blocked

[image: ajax response from the server]

```
These are part of my routes 

    r := gin.Default()
    //r := gin.New()

    config := cors.DefaultConfig()
    config.AllowOrigins = []string{"*"}
    // config.AllowOrigins = []string{"http://google.com", "http://facebook.com"}
    // config.AllowAllOrigins = true
    r.Use(cors.New(config))

    //system routes
    router.NotFound(r)
    router.NoMethods(r)

    //static routes
    router.ServeStatic(r)
Methods 

func NotFound(route *gin.Engine) {
    route.NoRoute(func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(404, gin.H{"msg": "Not Found"})
    })
}

func NoMethods(route *gin.Engine) {
    route.NoMethod(func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(405, gin.H{"msg": "Not allowed"})
    })
}

//Serve frontend static files

func ServeStatic(route *gin.Engine) {
    route.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("./views/public", true)))
    route.Use(auth.CORSMiddleware())
    api := route.Group("/api")

    {
        api.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
                "message": "pong",
            })
        })
    }
```

The go version is go version go1.18.1 linux/amd64

```
"axios": "^0.24.0",
"react": "^18.1.0",
```

Comment: If you're confused by that error message, read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards

Comment: Also, there's no point in `access-control-allow-origin` and `access-control-allow-headers` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header. You should take the time to familiarise with CORS a bit more.

Comment: The question is since all origins have been permitted, with a wildcard, and even with the resource domain in one instance, why is it still being blocked by gin

Comment: Please remove the comments: whether those lines are commented in your actual code is unclear. Then please show the CORS error message you get with your CORS configuration (using Gin).

Answer (score 1):

Try to move CORS middleware before your handleFunc

Example:

```
func (h *Handler) InitRoutes() *gin.Engine {
    router := gin.New()

    router.Use(h.setHeaders)

    router.GET("/", h.getRecordsByFilter)
    router.GET("/:uuid", h.getRecordByUuid)
    router.POST("/", h.createRecord)
    router.PUT("/:uuid", h.updateRecord)
    router.DELETE("/:uuid", h.deleteRecord)

    return router
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with credentials true from the react front-end

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    const {email,password} = this.state;
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/auth/register",
    {email: email, password: password},{
        withCredentials: true}).then(response => {
            console.log("registration res", response);
            console.log("response data",response.data);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("registratino error", error);
        });


    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: You should be able to accept this answer, in order to mark your problem as resolved.